# Vim script to switch between header and implementation file using cscope

Tags: vim, cscope

I currently use the [A.vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easily_switch_between_source_and_header_file) plugin to swap between header and implementation file. The limitation of this script is that it only works if both are in the same folder.

If you have a cscope database for your code you can easily find the header for a particular implementation file by doing `:cscope find f ImplementationFileName.h`.

How would you script this to take the current file name without the extension and search for that name with the added .h suffix?

Comment: no cscope requirement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170902/in-vim-how-to-switch-quickly-between-h-and-cpp-files-with-the-same-name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be possible out of the box using A.vim.  Check out :help alternate-config.  Specifically the section on search paths:

> b) Search Paths: In many projects the
>   location of the source files and the
>   corresponding header files is not
>   always the same directory. This plugin
>   allows the search path it uses to
>   locate source and header files to be
>   configured. The search path is
>   specified by setting the
>   g:alternateSearchPath variable. The
>   default setting is as follows,
>
> `g:alternateSearchPath =
>   'sfr:../source,sfr:../src,sfr:../include,sfr:../inc'`
>
> This indicates that the corresponding
>   file will be searched for in
>   ../source, ../src. ../include and
>   ../inc all relative to the current
>   file being switched from. The value of
>   the g:alternateSearchPath variable is
>   simply a comma separated list of
>   prefixes and directories. The "sfr:"
>   prefix indicates that  the path is
>   relative to the file. Other prefixes
>   are "wdr:" which indicates that the
>   directory is relative to the current
>   working directory and "abs:" which
>   indicates the path is absolute. If no
>   prefix is specified "sfr:" is assumed.

Comment: Great tip. The advantage of the cscope approach is that it doesn't matter where the include files are. The reason it doesn't work sometimes is that this particular project has include files in a non-standard location. Rather than add-in project specific paths to g:alternateSearchPath, it would be nice to fall back to my cscope index.